# Which is the understood subject of "Rejoicing."

Tags: present-tense, past-participles

Garbo plays the role of the queen, rejoicing in the love she has found with Antonio.

I understand that present participle has an understood subject. So in this case, which one is it?

source:
https://sentencedict.com/queen.html
（I read it here, but I can't find the original source）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be either "Garbo" (the name of an actor) or "the Queen" (a character in a movie, almost certainly Queen Christina, in the film of the same name).

Since Antonio is also a character in the same film (Don Antonio de la Prada played by John Gilbert) so I understand that *the Queen* was rejoicing in her love. Thus the context and knowledge of the film makes the grammatical ambiguity go away.

The use of the word "rejoice in" is unusual, it means little more than "be happy about" or "enjoy". It is an older use of the word "rejoice". The queen is enjoying the love of Antonio.